# HDFS Data node Reconnects on failure/Restart

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a functionality, configuration in HDFS, wherein if a data node fails/restarts, upon restarting it would be able to reconnect to the cluster and transact data?

Answer (score 0):

Once the namenode detects an RPC connection to a running datanode process, yes, it can transact data.

Whether the datanode process starts on a reboot is up to your installation & OS

For example, the latest version of Apache Ambari supports Service Auto start

Answer (score 0):

The main configuration files related to HDFS are `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`. These configuration files will be present in all the nodes where hdfs is running or hdfs is accessible (namenode, datanode or hdfs client). The core-site.xml has the property that helps to identify the namenode. With this property, the hdfs related requests will be able to identify the namenode.

```
 <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://${namenodehost:port}</value>
 </property>
```

When a datanode restarts, it identifies the namenode using this property and sends an RPC call to the namenode (heartbeat) and registers itself. It is the datanode who sends the requests to the namenode and makes the registration. This is the default behaviour of a properly configured hadoop cluster and it doesnt need any additional configuration. The data directory of the datanode (`dfs.datanode.data.dir`) has a metadata related to the hdfs cluster (`/dfs/dn/current/VERSION`). This file has an entry called `clusterID`. Sample content is given below

```
#Wed Nov 15 19:34:53 IST 2017
storageID=DS-8837a585-1906-47ab-b28b-a1183c47adf8
clusterID=cluster4
cTime=0
datanodeUuid=8efd145f-453b-4d79-8073-2efe33f451d2
storageType=DATA_NODE
layoutVersion=-56
```

The datanode registration will fail if the `clusterID` of the configured namenode is different from the `clusterID` present in the datanode.

The data transaction will happen after the proper registration of the datanode to the HDFS. Even if a datanode is kept stopped for several days, the datanode can reconnect to the namenode.